# Making a form letter in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Is there a way to make and save a form letter in outlook 2007. I have to send out the same letter several  times a year to different people.

Comment: When you say a form letter, do you mean a template with different fields to be updated on a per person basis or just a standard, unchanging content?

Answer (score 1):

I did find a great way to handle this.  First you create a custom toolbar in Word which will appear as a toolbar in Outlook.   Also in Word you create your original message and copy it as a new AutoText.  That Autotext can then be attached to your custom toolbar and is now available in Outlook any time you need to send out that message with one click of the toolbar menu!   Works great and is easy to set up.  Using menus on your custom toolbar you can even create "categories" of letters if you have a lot of them that you regularly send out.

Answer (score 0):

You could create it in Word then send it as an attachement.

Comment: I have been saving it in word and doing a copy and paste, into a new email . But I was hoping there was a better workaround.

Comment: What about the Tools>>Forms>>Design a form, you should be able to save and re-use those? Ah, I take it you can't alter the content, just the layout